# Normalization of DB

Tags: mysql, database-design, optimization

I have designed a database using MySQL likewise
[image: ER Diagram of DB]

My question is what else i can do to normalize the DB, for now i am using InnoDB engine for the table to maintain the relation among different tables.

Comment: add more clear image...

Comment: @dev: the original version of the image can be found here: http://i.stack.imgur.com/k9klv.png (If you have editing privileges, you can edit the question to see the url.)

Comment: @ashofphoenix: Why do you have a separate table for user_profile? Can one login have more than one profile?

Comment: @MarkBannister: The reason i have separated the user_login and user_profile because i need to query the user_profile many times to get user info while user_login table is for authentication purpose only, so i thought it would be better to keep user-info and user-login related field in separate tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it really depends on "how normal is normal", there are 6+ forms.

comment table is normalized (assuming a user can comment more than once on a vid. how about a date field?)

like table is not really normalized, unless a user can like a video more than once. you could kill the likeId. also, date field would be handy.

video_list.meta suggests a denormalized field

follower_list is not quite right, as the same user can follow the same follower more than once. kill the followId field. you can have fkeys on more than one field.

user_profile is reasonably normalized, though some fields will be null, suggesting not full normalization.

user_login is not fully normalized, as they might have a fbId but not a twitterId or emailId.

Answer (score 0):

It seems fine by me. I would say that the structure is fully normalized.

Answer (score 0):

To be properly normalised, the profile and login tables should be one single table (as long as there is a one-to-one relationship between them). From the available information, there doesn't appear to be any benefit to splitting them.

Answer (score 0):

Followerid seems unnecessary (you can just use a 2 column primary key).

Address probably wants to be on another table (then you can normalise parts of the address such as town name).

Parent_id on the videos table doesn't seem to relate to anything.

Otherwise seems fine for normalisation.

Comment: The parentId on the video table is related to the primary key of table itself.It is there to find if record having some parent or not i have defined the default values as 0 for record which doesn't have any parent associated.